# "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" , (New form (new_main.ui) not displaying after splash screen in PYQT5 ()

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, splash-screen, pyqt6

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QProgressBar, QLabel, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QMainWindow
import new_main


class SplashScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Spash Screen Example')
        self.setFixedSize(1100, 500)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.counter = 0
        self.n = 300  # total instance
        self.initUI()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.loading)
        self.timer.start(15)


    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.labelTitle = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelTitle.setObjectName('LabelTitle')

        # center labels
        self.labelTitle.resize(self.width() - 10, 150)
        self.labelTitle.move(0, 40)  # x, y
        #self.labelTitle.setText(' 3PP Sheet Automation')
        self.labelTitle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.labelDescription = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelDescription.resize(self.width() - 10, 50)
        self.labelDescription.move(0, self.labelTitle.height())
        self.labelDescription.setObjectName('LabelDesc')
        self.labelDescription.setText('<strong>Loading.</strong>')
        self.labelDescription.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self.frame)
        self.progressBar.resize(self.width() - 200 - 10, 50)
        self.progressBar.move(100, self.labelDescription.y() + 130)
        self.progressBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.progressBar.setFormat('%p%')
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(True)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, self.n)
        self.progressBar.setValue(20)

        self.labelLoading = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelLoading.resize(self.width() - 10, 50)
        self.labelLoading.move(0, self.progressBar.y() + 70)
        self.labelLoading.setObjectName('LabelLoading')
        self.labelLoading.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        #self.labelLoading.setText('loading...')

    def loading(self):
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.counter)

        if self.counter == int(self.n * 0.3):
            self.labelDescription.setText('<strong>Loading...</strong>')
        elif self.counter == int(self.n * 0.6):
            self.labelDescription.setText('<strong>Loading.....</strong>')
        elif self.counter == int(self.n * 0.9):
            self.labelDescription.setText('<strong>Loading.......</strong>')
        elif self.counter == int(self.n * 0.9):
            self.labelDescription.setText('<strong>Loading........</strong>')
        elif self.counter >= self.n:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.close()
            time.sleep(1)
            mainform = Input_form()
            self.mainform.show()


        self.counter += 1



class Input_form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.uic.loadUi('new_mian.ui', self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # don't auto scale when drag app to a different monitor.
    # QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        #LabelTitle {
            font-size: 60px;
            color: #93deed;
        }

        #LabelDesc {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #c2ced1;
        }

        #LabelLoading {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #e8e8eb;
        }

        QFrame {
            background-color: black;
            color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
        }

        QProgressBar {
            background-color: #DA7B93;
            color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
            border-style: none;
            border-radius: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        QProgressBar::chunk {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad x1:0, x2:1, y1:0.511364, y2:0.523, stop:0 #1C3334, stop:1 #376E6F);
        }
    ''')

 
    splash = SplashScreen()
    splash.show()
  

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

After successful splash screen loading , i am trying to disply new_mian.ui (QmainWindow) form created through QT Designer and imported in code as well.

I also generated python file with this  "pyuic5 new_main.ui -o new_main.py" command but its prompting error "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" . I am new to Pyqt and not able to understand why it is so. Please guide. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the main script of your program? Where is the code for `new_main`?

Comment: I created new_main from QT Designer and converted .ui file to .py file and than imported in code. I selected type of new_main.ui as  QmainWindow while creating form. Thanks

Comment: I didn't ask what you did, please read more carefully the first question and, as the second suggests, provide the code of the other file.

Comment: @Qazi_Ameer_Hammad Either use PyQt5 or use PyQt6, not both.